# Adding argument By vs WebElement - Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I just took a course about Selenium, and the teacher in certain situations created two methods with different argument, however there were no explanation about the differences.

```
public void waitForWebElementAndClick(By by) {
// place for some code
}
public void waitForWebElementAndClick(WebElement element) {
// place for some code
}
```

Can you guys help me a little bit what is the scenario where it has meaning to have two different method? In the course the teacher used only the WebElement so I had no chance to see and understand a scenario when we need the one with the By type argument and because of it I cannot see also the benefit or the drawbacks for using one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `By` is a locator. You would use it when either you haven't located the element yet or you need to locate it again. The majority of time, I use methods that take locators instead of WebElements because you avoid issues like stale element exceptions, etc.

But, sometimes you go through a complicated process to find an element and you want to do something further with it. In these cases, you would use the method that accepts a `WebElement`.

A simple version of the `By` version would be

```
public void waitForWebElementAndClick(By locator) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}
```

It uses `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element to be clickable and then clicks it. There are a couple downsides to this method. The first is that the wait is a fixed time, 20s.

We can improve it by adding a parameter for the timeout.

```
public static void waitForWebElementAndClick(By locator, int timeOutInSeconds) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeOutInSeconds)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();
}
```

Now we can vary the timeout, as needed.

The second downside is that it doesn't handle possible exceptions like `ElementClickInterceptedException` and `StaleElementReferenceException`. This is the method that I use in my framework with both improvements.

```
public static void waitForWebElementAndClick(By locator, int timeOutInSeconds) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    while (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(now.plusSeconds(timeOutInSeconds))) {
        try {
            new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeOutInSeconds)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click();

            return;
        } catch (ElementClickInterceptedException | StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            // do nothing, loop again
        }
    }
}
```

It has a custom wait period and if we run into one of the two handled exceptions, it just keeps trying until it either succeeds or times out.

The simple version of the `WebElement` version would be

```
public static void waitForWebElementAndClick(WebElement webElement) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement)).click();
}
```

It can also be customized with a timeout parameter and exception handling as above. One issue with using a `WebElement` in this case is that once you get a stale element exception, you cannot fix it for a `WebElement`. The "fix" is to refetch the element from the page and you need a locator to do that. That's one of the reasons why I prefer methods that take locators instead of `WebElement`s.